# New to DevOps and CI/CD

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, pipeline, continuous-deployment, sre

like I said in the title I'm new to DevOps and CI/CD. I don't have much experience (except for online tutorials) and I'm looking to start a project (nothing huge) that will be using automated CI/CD pipelines for all microservices.

Question is, what should I be using? There's an abundance of tools avilable.. Jenkins, CicleCI, TravisCI, DroneCI, GitLabCI, BitbucketCI, etc. It's becoming extremely confusing as to whether they are the same or not. Which of them would be the best to use in parallel with K8s, for many small microservice deployments?

Sorry if it sounds silly. First question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question. This question will surely lead to highly opinionated answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Kubernetes in parallel with Drone.io for a few months and would recommend it to you as well. In the past I used Jenkins but had to migrate the pipelines due to its limitations. At the end of the day it's a matter of preference and it is going to depend a lot on the project you're working on.

Pros for Drone.io:

- Free
- Open source
- Built on Docker (easy setup)
- Integrates with GitHub and BitBucket
- Used in production by many large companies (good skill to add on your CV)